# Weird JSON parse Error Android

Tags: android

I am getting a NullPointerException becauase of this LogCat message:

```
02-17 13:01:10.766: W/System.err(950): org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-17 13:01:10.775: W/System.err(950):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
```

This is what my JSON is outputting:

```
[{"rated":"1","user_id":""}]
```

And here is how I am retrieving it:

```
try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            sb2.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb2.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is2.close();
            resulttt=sb2.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{
            jArray2 = new JSONArray(resulttt);
            JSONObject json_data=null;

            rateresult = new int[jArray2.length()]; 
            rateuser = new String[jArray2.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
                rateresult[i]=json_data.getInt("rated");
                rateuser[i]=json_data.getString("user_id");
            }
        }
```

Any idea what is causing this "mismatch" or weird value in my LogCat? THanks.

Comment: What does "resulttt" look like.  Is it possible you getting back a JSON object instead of a JSON array with only one element?

Comment: You're not getting the exception because of a message in the log, you're getting it because you're using the wrong Charset ;) See SLaks answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a UTF8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
You need to read the stream as UTF8, not ISO-8859-1.

Comment: You are awesome! My other php files read fine with ISO-8859-1 and this one did too before I switched web hosts.. do you know what caused it to break?